# Cannot resolve symbol 'quickstart'

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to use the sample code of Firebase auth using Email and Password:
[EmailPasswordActivity.java](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/c2f3ae5a111028cdfe86e53f5d59915f8ef0917e/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/EmailPasswordActivity.java),  I get a "`Cannot resolve symbol 'quickstart'`", which appears in this line:
`import com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.R;`

why is that?

Comment: Clean your project and try again, does it work?

Comment: have you added firebase to your project?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Firebase guide and its quickstart code.
The project is called 'auth' and in its manifest you can find:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth">
```

To solve your problem, you can change the package tag with `com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth` or you can change the import `import com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.R;` with `<your package in your manifest>.R`.